# Different browsers show different behaviour with input type file

Tags: php, forms, file, cross-browser

I have 2 file upload fields in my form. Both look like this:

```
<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" accept="application/pdf,application/msword">
<span id="file1_status">Currently uploaded: <?php echo $file1_fileName; ?></span>
<input type="file" id="file2" name="file2" accept="application/pdf,application/msword">
<span id="file2_status">Currently uploaded: <?php echo $file2_fileName; ?></span>
```

where $file1/2_fileName; is either "none" when the page is first loaded or equal to $_FILES["file1/2"]["name"] after a post event.

Toward the end of the page, I do

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  jQuery("input#file1").change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    _('file1_status').innerHTML = "Currently uploaded: " + val.substr(12); // removes C:/fakedir/
  });
```

Same for file2. So, basically if someone uploads "file.pdf", there is a text under the file input that reads: "Currently uploaded: file.pdf". I do this so the user sees that the file is still there if form validation fails after form submission.

OK so far so good.

Rather than using "required" in the input file field, upon form submission, I do the following:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"])) {
 // check mime_type, file size, etc.
} else {
 // display an error below the input field that a file is missing.
}
```

Same for file2. Now to the actual question/problem.
Imagine the following situation. A user only uploads file1 but forgets file2 and clicks submit. This is what happens:

**Firefox** (latest version): Below the file1 field the status  still shows "Currently uploaded: file1.pdf" and below the file2 input field an error message is displayed to remind the user to upload this file also. If the user complies and uploads file2, then clicks on submit again, the form is submitted and all is fine, i.e., both files have been attached to the form submission. This is the expected behaviour.

**Chome/Edge**: For the same user behavouir everything is the same except for when the user clicks on submit a second time. For some reason, both these browsers now show an error below the file1 input field (although it still shows "Currently uploaded: file.pdf" which the user uploaded in the very beginning). So for some reason, and although $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"] is not empty, the test
`is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"])`  fails upon the second form submission in both Chrome and Edge but not in FF.

This is very confusing. Why is this and how can this be avoided/fixed?

Comment: You haven't told us how the form is submitted. There are basically 2 methods. 1. The traditional one, which reloads the whole page/iframe. 2. Using AJAX, which keeps the contents of the page and form. My _guess_ is that you're using the first one? My second guess is that this is a security feature. You shouldn't be able to set a file input to point to a file on an user's computer, only the user should be able to do this. This doesn't explain why it seems to work in Firefox.

Comment: This question would be helped with an actual [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Remember that, to really help you, we would probably need to create one anyway, and guess what code you're actually using. By providing an example you make your question easier to answer.

Comment: `id="file1" "file1"` is missing the `name=` part

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: Yes the form is submitted by simply reloading the page `<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" name="mssubmit" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">`. The actual page is about 500 lines of code so I will try to come up with a shortened example.

Comment: @brombeer: Sorry, that was just a typo here. It's correct in the actual code. I have corrected it here now.

Comment: Please don't forget to test your shorter example, to make sure it does what you describe in the question. I'm sure you've already thought of that, but I've seen many questions with a nice example that didn't do what was described in the question.  Anyway, if proven to be true, this seems like a very interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Edge/Chrome behaviour is indeed to expected/normal behaviour. To my great embarrassment I have not been able to reproduce the above behaviour in FF anymore so I am not exactly sure what happened because I really did see a different behaviour while testing it for about an hour or so.

Anyway, for all practical purposes, I was able to work around the issue by moving the files that met all my criteria (re mime types, file size, etc) into a temporary upload directory on my server, store the file name in a session variable, and modify this code:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"])) {
 // check mime_type, file size, etc.
} else {
 // display an error below the input field that a file is missing.
}
```

to this

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"])) {
 // check mime_type, file size, and if OK move to upload directory on server and store the name of the successfully uploaded file in $_SESSION["file1"]
} elseif (!empty($_SESSION["file1"])) { //basically this gets invoked the second time round, i.e., when the user uploads the 2nd file they forgot when submitting the form for the first time
   $file1_fileName = $_SESSION["file1"]; // used to display under the input file element (see above)
} else {
 // display an error below the input field that a file is missing.
}
```

Same for file2. So while the first "if" condition fails upon the 2nd form submission, the "elseif" condition is true and no error is issued.

Comment: Nice to hear you worked it out. You could have discovered a bug in Firefox....